# How to 'Input' & 'Click' with Javascript in another window

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping

How do insert a new search term after the page has been loaded? And subsequently use .trigger('click'); to execute that search?

```
var search = "search keyword";

function myFunction() {
    var newWin = window.open("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" + search);     
}
```

I want to be able to input a search term on my page and "click" the search button using javascript.

```
var newWin = window.open(https://www.google.com/);
newWin.document.getElementById('gbqfba').click();
```

The end goal is that I will be using this on another site that I will be indexing data but I wanted to become familiar with it on google, if possible.

Comment: 1) `click()` is not a JS function. 2) If the new window loads a page from a different domain, you won't be able to access its document(s) in any way due to Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Then how do I submit a form on another page?

Comment: To submit a form you can use the submit() function, e.g. `document.forms[0[.submit()`. You can do this with any form that are from the same origin (domain) than the document where the JS is loaded that tries to submit the form.